# Работа ссылок с++

Tags: c++, объекты, ссылки

У меня возникло много вопросов, касательно ссылок? Вообщем, насколько я понял ссылка не является [объектом](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

> The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function,
> enumerator, type, non-static class member, template, class or function
> template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this.

Соответственно из этого можно сделать вывод, что она не хранится ни где в памяти, т. к. у нее нельзя взять адрес. Так же из определения [ссылки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference):

> Declares a named variable as a reference, that is, an alias to an
> already-existing object or function.

Можно сделать вывод, что ссылка, это некоторое подобие макроса, то есть если очень грубо:

```
#define b_ref b
int b = 1;
cout << b_ref;
```

Будет в некоторой степени эквивалентно этому:

```
int b = 1;
int b_ref = b;
cout << b_ref;
```

P. s. я не говорю, что эти 2 примера полностью равны, я просто сравниваю работу ссылки с макросом, т. к. мне кажется, что тут присутствуют общие черты.

Но так-же есть еще и `r-value ссылки`. То есть сделав такую вещь:

```
int a&& = 1;
```

Мы не будем создавать, переменную, которая занимает некоторое место в памяти, мы очень, если очень грубо говоря, сделаем так:

```
#define a 1
```

И получится так, что мы сможем хранить значение `1`, не занимая при этом памяти. Не могли бы вы меня поправить, или как то дополнить все вышесказанное, заранее огромное спасибо:)

Comment: `The following entities are not objects: value, reference, ... Соответственно из этого можно сделать вывод, что она не хранится ни где в памяти`. Не совсем понятно, как вы  сделали подобный вывод из приведённой цитаты. Ок, объекты занимают память. Ок, ссылка не является объектом. Но ведь, строго говоря, в приведённой цитате не сказано, что если нечто не объект, то оно обязательно не требует памяти (storage).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ссылка не является объектом

Да.

> можно сделать вывод, что она не хранится ни где в памяти

Нет. Хотя они так хитро описаны в стаднате, под капотом у ссылок все равно указатели.<sup>1</sup>

В отдельных случаях компилятор может их соптимизировать, чтобы они не занимали память. Но ничего не мешает сделать то же самое с указателями (хотя это и сложнее, потому что указатели можно переприсваивать).

То, что они не являются объектами, формально не дает вручную читать и менять составляющие их байты (адрес объекта, на который они указывают), и не дает использовать их в качестве элементов массивов (и еще чего-то).

В остальном это те же указатели<sup>1</sup>, но с другим интерфейсом.

> она не хранится ни где в памяти, т. к. у нее нельзя взять адрес

Положите ее в структуру. Увидите, что размер структуры станет равным размеру указателя.<sup>1</sup> Возьмите адрес структуры - чем не адрес ссылки? Формально это не ее адрес, да, она же не объект. Но если посмотреть, что по этому адресу - там скорее всего окажется указатель на то, на что указывает ссылка.

> из определения ссылки: Declares a named variable as ... an alias to an already-existing object

Это вообще ничего не значит. Это просто "научно-популярное" определение.

> То есть сделав такую вещь:
>
> ```
> int a&& = 1;
> ```
>
> Мы не будем создавать, переменную, которая занимает некоторое место в памяти

Единственная **переменная** здесь - ссылка `a`. Но **объект** типа `int` все равно существует.

`1`, как prvalue, объектом не является. Но попытка инициализировать им ссылку "материализует" его (подвергает [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization)) что делает его xvalue - вполне реальным объектом типа `int`.

У `a` даже адрес можно взять.

---

<sup>1</sup> Стандарт не гарантирует, что у ссылок под капотом указатели, но на практике это так. Не видел и не слышал ни про один компилятор, который делал бы по-другому.

Comment: `В остальном это те же указатели, но с другим интерфейсом.`  Либо сразу поясняйте, что имеете ввиду, конкретные способы реализации ссылок некоторыми компиляторами, либо сразу кидайте пруф на стандарт языка, что добавление ссылки в структуру, увеличит её размер как минимум на размер указателя.

Comment: @wololo Я и не говорю, что в стандарте так написано. Это то, как происходит в реальности. Найдете компилятор, на котором это не так? Но пояснение сейчас добавлю.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не могли бы вы сказать, для чего нужны r-value ссылки, когда можно создать обычную переменную?

Comment: @n1kzzz Таким способом их редко используют. Обычно их ставят в параметры функций, чтобы функции принимали только rvalue но не lvalue.

Comment: 1) `Найдете компилятор, на котором это не так?` Думаю вы знаете ответ на этот вопрос :) 2) Посмотрите другие вопросы ТС. Он активно мешает в одну кучу стандарт языка, алгоритмы работы компиляторов и ассемблер. Пытается применить стандарт языка к внутренним алгоритмам работы компиляторов, либо наоборот из того факта, что «под капотом» ссылки — это указатели, делает вывод, что с точки зрения стандарта ссылка обязана занимать `N` байт. Просто написав без пояснений, `что размер структуры станет равным размеру укзателя` вы его только запутаете (моё личное мнение, на истинность не претендую).

Comment: @wololo Тут должен быть компромисс между формальной правильностью, и понятностью ответа. :) Подписал в спорных местах, что это не строго из стандарта.

Comment: Ссылки на элемент класса ( или функцию ) имеют размер 16 байт.

Comment: @AlexGlebe А разве такие ссылки бывают? Пример кода бы. Указатели-на-члены да, обычно в два раза толще обычных указателей, но спорно, являются ли они вообще указателями (`std::is_pointer_v<...>` для них `false`).

Comment: Своим примером (ссылка в структуре) вы заставили меня серьёзно призадуматься. Что произойдёт с точки зрения стандарта, если мы через указатели начнём изменять ту часть структуры, в которой хранится ссылка? Примерно [вот так](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/150ddce3816452e6).

Comment: @wololo UB наверное ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Если бы так было можно, не было бы всяких "не является объектом" и т. д.